# ¿Cómo remover query string repetido?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Lo que sucede es que yo genero urls amigables mediante `.htaccess`, y no quiero que se repita el mismo query string que obtiene el valor a mostrar.

Digamos ésta es mi url amigable:

```
http://url.com/hola-mundo
```

Y ésta es la url original:

```
http://url.com/?query=hola-mundo
```

Pero no quiero permitir introducir esto en el navegador:

```
http://url.com/hola-mundo?query=hola-mundo
```

Quiero eliminar `?query=hola-mundo` en el navegador del cliente sin que afecte al resto de la URL, que solo quede `http://url.com/hola-mundo`.

Las reglas que utilizo son éstas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúüÑñ\&]+)$ /?query=$1 [NC,L]
```

Y esta otro para reemplazar todos los espacios y %20 en la url :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[a-zA-Z\_\-]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2? [NE,R,L]
```

También tengo esta última regla:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://url.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65529/discussion-on-question-by-eddy-otsutsuki-como-remover-query-string-repetido).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es hacer una redirección de navegador (y no interna dentro de Apache) para que cambie la URL del navegador del cliente a la misma URL sin la cadena de consulta:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R,QSD]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-ÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúüÑñ\&]+)$ /?query=$1 [NC,L]
```

Por un lado `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$` comprueba si la cadena de consulta tiene al menos un carácter y `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$` comprueba que no se trate del directorio raíz al que rediriges las URLs amigables.

En caso de cumplirse ambas condiciones `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301,QSD]` redirige de manera permanente (se guarda en la caché del navegador del cliente) a la misma URL eliminando la cadena de consulta con [`QSD`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd).

Para las pruebas deja sólo `R`, en caso contrario cualquier error en las reglas deberás corregirlo limpiando la caché del navegador del cliente.

Comment: De verdad muchas gracias. :)

Comment: De nada, un placer ayudar :)